# regex search in datatables that is connected to a database

Tags: php, mysql, regex, datatables

I am trying to be able to a regex search in [datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) that is connected to a database.

The code I have currently handles searching(see 3 below):

```
if( !empty($requestData['search']['value']) ) {
    // if there is a search parameter
    $sql = "SELECT first_name, last_name, position, office, start_date, salary";
    $sql.=" FROM $table";
    $sql.=" WHERE first_name LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";    // $requestData['search']['value'] contains search parameter
    $sql.=" OR last_name LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR position LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR office LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR start_date LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR salary LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";

    $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("employee-grid-data.php: get employees-456");
    $totalFiltered = mysqli_num_rows($query); // when there is a search parameter then we have to modify total number filtered rows as per search result without limit in the query 

    $sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."   LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   "; // $requestData['order'][0]['column'] contains colmun index, $requestData['order'][0]['dir'] contains order such as asc/desc , $requestData['start'] contains start row number ,$requestData['length'] contains limit length.
    $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("employee-grid-data.php: get employees-789"); // again run query with limit

} else {    

    $sql = "SELECT first_name, last_name, position, office, start_date, salary";
    $sql.=" FROM $table";

    $sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."   LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";
    $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("employee-grid-data.php: get employees 000");

}
```

What I want to be able to do is do a regex accross the data (see 2 below).**How would I write the above code to do this?**

I have tried this (replaced LIKE with REGEXP and removed the %) but can not get it to work, which i am beginnig to wonder if there is more to it?

```
$sql = "SELECT first_name, last_name, position, office, start_date, salary";
$sql.=" FROM $table";
$sql.=" WHERE first_name REGEXP '".$requestData['search']['value']."' ";    // $requestData['search']['value'] contains search parameter
$sql.=" OR last_name REGEXP '".$requestData['search']['value']."' ";
$sql.=" OR position REGEXP '".$requestData['search']['value']."' ";
$sql.=" OR office REGEXP '".$requestData['search']['value']."' ";
$sql.=" OR start_date REGEXP '".$requestData['search']['value']."' ";
$sql.=" OR salary REGEXP '".$requestData['search']['value']."' ";
```

1 - This is my dataset:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM datatables_demo;                                           +----+------------+-----------+-------------+--------+------------+--------+
| id | first_name | last_name | position    | office | start_date | salary |
+----+------------+-----------+-------------+--------+------------+--------+
|  1 | Tiger      | Nixon     | Accountant  | Tokyo  | 2016-11-08 | 320800 |
|  2 | Garrett    | Winters   | Accountant2 | Tokyo  | 2016-11-08 | 170750 |
|  3 | Ashton     | Cox       | Accountant3 | Tokyo  | 2016-11-08 |  86000 |
|  4 | Cedric     | Kelly     | Accountant4 | Tokyo  | 2016-11-08 | 433060 |
|  5 | Tiger5     | Nixon     | Accountant  | Tokyo  | 2016-11-08 | 320800 |
+----+------------+-----------+-------------+--------+------------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

2 - This is a regex example:

```
mysql> SELECT first_name, last_name, position, office, start_date, salary FROM datatables_demo WHERE first_name REGEXP '^[TG]';
+------------+-----------+-------------+--------+------------+--------+
| first_name | last_name | position    | office | start_date | salary |
+------------+-----------+-------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Tiger      | Nixon     | Accountant  | Tokyo  | 2016-11-08 | 320800 |
| Garrett    | Winters   | Accountant2 | Tokyo  | 2016-11-08 | 170750 |
| Tiger5     | Nixon     | Accountant  | Tokyo  | 2016-11-08 | 320800 |
+------------+-----------+-------------+--------+------------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

3 - This is a regular search example:

```
mysql> SELECT first_name, last_name, position, office, start_date, salary FROM datatables_demo WHERE first_name LIKE '%ti%';
+------------+-----------+------------+--------+------------+--------+
| first_name | last_name | position   | office | start_date | salary |
+------------+-----------+------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Tiger      | Nixon     | Accountant | Tokyo  | 2016-11-08 | 320800 |
| Tiger5     | Nixon     | Accountant | Tokyo  | 2016-11-08 | 320800 |
+------------+-----------+------------+--------+------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: " have tried this (replaced LIKE with REGEXP and removed the %) but can not get it to work, which i am beginnig to wonder if there is more to it?" yes yo have to actually write a valid regular expression. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Comment: `$sql.=" WHERE first_name LIKE '$requestData['search']['value']' ";` this might be it?

Comment: You might get more attention for this question if you tag it as [tag:mysql] instead of [tag:sql-server]. Microsoft [tag:sql-server] does not have the REGEXP keyword.

Comment: What is wrong?  Keep in mind that the wild cards are different between `LIKE` and `REGEXP`.